# Preencher tabela array

Tags: html, ajax, data, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá, estou a desenvolver um projeto web mas não consigo o resultado desejado. Eu tenho um arquivo php que me retorna um array de veículos e meu Index chama esse arquivo para obter esse array através do ajax. Ao pesquisar no Index, ele retorna a parte da matriz que corresponde ao que procurei, mas gostaria de preencher a tabela com os dados e não imprimir um array puro na página. Obrigado a quem ajudar !!

Meu código:

```html
  $(document).on('click', '#pesquisa', function () {
                    showPesquisa();
                    clearResponse();
                });
                // show home page
                function showPesquisa() {

                    var html = `
                    <style>
        body {background-image: url("imagens/5series.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        color: #FFFFFF
        </style>     
            <h2>Pesquisar</h2>  
            <form id='search_form'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" id="s" required placeholder='insira o seu nome'/>
                </div>
            </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="search_btn">Pesquisar</button>
                
     
        <div class="container">
   <table class="table table bordered" id="veiculosTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Identificador</th>
          <th>Categoria</th>
          <th>Marca</th>
          <th>Modelo</th>
          <th>Lugares</th>
          <th>€/dia</th>
          <th>Combustível</th>
          <th>Portas</th>
          <th>Caixa</th>
          <th>Empresa</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
</div>
            
      
            `;

                    clearResponse();
                    $('#content').html(html);
                };
                
//$("#search_btn").click(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#search_btn', function () {  
    var search_form = $("#search_form");
    var search_data = JSON.stringify(search_form.serializeObject());
    
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/veiculo/search.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: search_data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#response').html("<div class='success'>"+JSON.stringify(response)+'</div>');
        },
                     error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                            // on error, tell the user sign up failed
                            $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Erro de pesquisa: "+xhr+" "+resp+" "+text+'</div>');
                        }
    });
});
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa iterar o JSON recebido e montar as linhas do `tbody` da tabela.

Primeiro coloque o id `resposta` no tbody, que é onde serão inseridas as linhas:

```
<tbody id="resposta"></tbody>
```

Depois, no success do AJAX, você monta a estrutura das linhas com os valores recebidos no JSON, conforme abaixo:

> *Repare que a array está dentro do objeto `records` do JSON. Logo, você deverá pegar e iterar a array dentro de `response.records`.*

```
success: function(response) {

   let tabela = ``; // declara a variável vazia

   // vai montando as linhas com os valores do JSON
   for(let item of response.records){
     tabela += `<tr>
         <td>${item.ID}</td>
         <td>${item.id_Categoria}</td>
         <td>${item.Marca}</td>
         <td>${item.Modelo}</td>
         <td>${item.Lugares}</td>
         <td>${item.Preco_dia}</td>
         <td>${item.Combustivel}</td>
         <td>${item.Portas}</td>
         <td>${item.Caixa}</td>
         <td>${item.Empresas_ID}</td>
      </tr>`;
   }

   $('#resposta').html(tabela); // insere tudo no tbody
},
```

Comment: Boas amigo, obrigado pela ajuda, mas infelizmente nao funcionou... Ele apresentou os resultados por cima da tabela e desformatados... O que será que posso melhorar?

Comment: O `id="response"` deve estar apenas no `tbody`. Deve ser isso a causa do problema.

Comment: Amigo, fiz uma alteração. Coloque no `tbody` outro id: `id="resposta"` e deixe o outro elemento com o `id="response"` como estava.

Comment: Funcionou amigo!!!!! Fiz <tbody id="resposta"></tbody> e fiz $('#resposta').html(veiculosTable);

Comment: Como faço isso amigo?

Comment: Ja está amigo, mais uma vez muito obrigado!! Grande abraço